# Is there a way to get a list of all VSCode extensions?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to build an "app" in python.
I want to add a list of all VSCode extensions to a PyQt5 list widget, but I have no idea how to get or create the list of all existing extensions.

I tried to find a API to do this but I am too dumb and probably looked over what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [market](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Installs) to get all extensions.

[image]

If you want to draw the extension into a list, you need to learn and use the **web crawler** technology.